# html form autocomplete from database in 2021

Tags: html, json, forms, autocomplete

There are many articles regarding how to autocomplete some input and related form widgets. The goal is to autocomplete user input with data from database (via json api) but send only the id(s) from database back to the server. There are two cases of usage:

1. simple id-name (or id-value) pairs
2. plus some "related" info (like - a dummy example, don't judge - select also the country when selecting a city)

Since ages, jquery autocomplete is used, it's working, but since jquery has become for too many people the "black sheep" I am looking for other possible solutions.

Existing solutions:

1. jquery-autocomplete + input.text (value) + input.hidden (id): it works, can be made bootstrap-friendly with some css, you can disable text send to server by not giving names to those input.text(s) so only required data is passed to the server, "related" data can be set through input/select ids; everything ok
2. jquery-autocomplete + input.text (value) with some data-id attribute; same as above, no need to add those hidden inputs, but you must "create" the post request (from javascript); sending json and using FormData with some javascript can make you life easier (at least for not-so-complicated forms); plus, you can (if you're lucky) access form inputs only by name (in case of multiple dynamically generated forms on the same page, to avoid id collision)
3. bootstrap-select2 is a nice candidate, unfortunately I don't like the idea of putting the input to the dropdown; plus, I'm not sure if you can use "related" info to populate other fields

You got the idea, I'm looking for something like 'editable/searchable select with dynamically fetch data'. Besides those solutions listed above, there is something else these days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of options available to "enhance" user selection with autocomplete forms (just because it looks more advanced, does not make it necessarily easier for users to use! Keep it in mind, it depends on your use-case, test it with end users if you can)

First, most people are not aware of the HTML5 native `<datalist>` element, which would cover your first case here without the need for any javascript.
It comes of course with limitations but is by far the cheapest option to consider:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Also a decent coverage among brothers, to be confirmed for your needs:

https://caniuse.com/datalist

If you are looking for more advanced controls, there are indeed plenty available but it depends on your stack, for instance if you use a frontend framework such as React or Vue and/or a UI library such as Material Design, Twitter Bootstrap, Bulma, Bumbag, (insert whichever UI library name here...):

- https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/
- https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/
- https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete
- https://bumbag.style/form/autosuggest/
- https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/autocomplete/
- https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html
- https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#Filtering-and-autocomplete
- https://koolamusic.github.io/chakra-ui-autocomplete/
- https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ (that one is jQuery based)

You may find those handy (they have their own customization options and limitations), with the caveat being the need to adopt their UI library and/or the framework itself.

Also just a final small note:

> since jquery has become for too many people the "black sheep" I am looking for other possible solutions

Just because more and more people think this way, does not mean it necessarily apply to your own project.
I no longer use jQuery myself those days because I usually run with with frontend frameworks, but for backend developers, I think it can still provide some benefits :)
If it works fine for you, there is nothing specifically wrong with it IMO.

Comment: first, thanks for the big list, I already knew couple of them, now it's time to look on everyone and see how each fits
I know about datalist, but the main problem is that input was created to store AND show a single value, but most autocomplete use cases are trying to do id:names maps (show the value but store some id), which is exactly what select does, but select is not searchable by default :-P
indeed, fashion sucks and blindly follow the trends is a no-no; but at least you must be informed about the trends and see how your code can fit in the big picture, because code is always evolving

Comment: mapping the id invisibly under the hood is arguably quite trivial, as long as you can reliably maintain the list from your database?
Worse case scenario, if the input itself does not provide the ID for you, you can map the value against your list (could be more complex if names from database are not unique though)

Comment: indeed, keeping the id is trivial, I provided two possible solutions in the question; but both of them are kind of "hacks" (adding hidden inputs, rewriting post request); I was looking for a "cleaner" solution, but I didn't find it yet, at least without using a front-end framework